# Hackerrank Gridland Metro - using Interval Cover Solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, interview-questions, interval

Hi there I was hoping to get a better grasp of greddy algorithms while trying to solve this problem: [Hackerrank: Gridland Metro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156887/hackerrank-gridland-metro) and I was trying to apply an algorithm where each grid could be considered a point, and each track as an interval which cover these points. Would appreciate any feedback in regards to my approach - as I'm failing a couple of test cases, but believe this approach could be applied.

Note: some code is missing for clarity:

```js
function gridlandMetro(n, m, k, track) {
  // Let's treat the railrods as intervals
  // And Lampposts as points
  // Need to figure out number of uncovered points.
  
  // Turn Matrix into a line
  // Such that railroad intervals will be
  // row * {start, end}
  const intervals = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < k; i++){
      const [row, start, end] = track[i];
      const interval = {
          // minus 1 since we want start of row
          start: ((row - 1) * m) + start,
          end: ((row - 1) * m) + end
      }
      intervals.push(interval);
  }
  minHeap(intervals) // create a priority queue with earliest start-time first
  
  let last = 0;
  let lamps = 0;
  while(intervals.length > 0){
      let i = deleteMin(intervals) //get railroad with earliest remaining start time
      if(i.start > last){
          //count any lamps inbetween intervals
          lamps += i.start - last - 1 
          last = i.end
      } else if(i.end > last){
          last = i.end // can extend the current interval further since some overlap
      }
  }
  lamps += m*n - last // calculate any remaining lampposts.
  return lamps;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, unlike Stack Overflow the more code we see the better review you will get. While reducing code for clarity on Stack Overflow is good, it is actually bad on this site. You should also include the text of the programming challenge as a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time - but it had to do with how large the Integers were being handled. I refactored the code to instead count consecutive non-railway cells, rather count the number of cells which had a track in them (using the interval merge method). I further had to break it down row by row to handle the big intergers:

```js
function gridlandMetro(n, m, k, track) {
  // Let's treat the railroads as overlapping intervals
  // Need to figure out total number of railroad cells
  // than remove those from final grid.
  
  // Organize tracks by row using a hash table
  const intervals = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < k; i++){
      const [row, start, end] = track[i];
      const interval = {
          start: start,
          end: end
      }
      if(!intervals.hasOwnProperty(row)){
          intervals[row] = [interval]
      } else {
        intervals[row].push(interval);
      }
  }

  let tracks = 0;
  //go row-by-row which contain tracks and count number of tracks
  for(let r in intervals){
    //minHeap sorts array by earliest start time first
    minHeap(intervals[r])
  
    let last_end = 0;
    while(intervals[r].length > 0){
        //remove the first interval from the array
        let i = deleteMin(intervals[r])

        if(i.start > last_end){
            // if this interval starts after the end of the last
            // activated interval record it and update new last_end
            tracks = i.end - i.start + 1 + tracks
            last_end = i.end
        } else if (i.end > last_end){
            // this interval overlaps a previous interval
            // record non-overlapping portion
            tracks = i.end - last_end + tracks // no +1 since last_end was already counted above
            last_end = i.end
        }
    }
  }

  // BigInt is important here otherwise fails some of the testcases.
  let lamps = BigInt(m) * BigInt(n) - BigInt(tracks);
  return lamps;
}
```

Helper functions for priority Queue:

```js
 function minHeap(arr){
  const t = arr.length >> 1
  for(let i = t; i >=0; i--){
      downHeap(arr,i+1)
  }
}
function downHeap(arr,t){
  let c = t << 1;
  if(c > arr.length) return
  //compare child nodes
  if(c < arr.length && arr[c-1].start > arr[c].start ) c++
  if(arr[c-1].start < arr[t-1].start){
      swap(arr, c-1, t-1)
      downHeap(arr, c)
  }
}
function swap(arr, l, r){
  const t = arr[l];
      arr[l] = arr[r]
      arr[r] = t
}
function deleteMin(arr){
  let n = arr.length -1;
  if(n < 0) return n
  const min = arr[0]
  arr[0] = arr[n];
  arr.length = n;
  downHeap(arr,1);
  return min;
}
```